# Errors vs Exceptions in JS - Are there exceptions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

**Error**

> Error objects are **thrown** when runtime errors occur. The Error object
> can also be used as a base object for **user-defined exceptions**. See
> below for standard built-in error types.

**Description**

> Runtime errors result in new Error objects being created and **thrown**.

According to MDN, can we say that **Errors are the same as Exceptions** because both are created with the `Error` class, or is there an `Exception` class in JavaScript?

Comment: The `Error` class is probably the best idea for objects to throw, but it's possible to throw (and catch) any value. Catching is not a typed operation, so a `catch` clause catches any and all thrown exception values.

Comment: When we talk about _"Exceptions"_, we usually mean any given thing that we _throw_ using some feature of a language, its rarely specific to any given type.

Comment: hi @Pointy thanks +1. "*so a catch clause catches any and **all thrown exception** values.*" - then, errors (`Error` class) are exceptions by the mere fact of being thrown with `throw`, that is, **everything thrown  with `throw` in JS** is considered an exception, ¿right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer yes, if you want to think about it that way. `throw 17;` is perfectly OK, and the `catch` clause would get the value 17. In JavaScript the thrown values are simple values of any type, including `undefined`.

Comment: Excellent @Pointy +1. One more thing to confirm, Errors and exceptions are therefore *syntactically synonymous* in JavaScript, since JS only uses the keyword `Error` for Errors and for exceptions, right?

Comment: `Error` is not a keyword; it's a built-in constructor like `Array` or `Map`. You can create an `Error` instance for any purpose with `new Error()`.

Comment: Perfect @Pointy +1 . "*You can create an Error instance for any purpose with new Error()*" -  As soon as we put the word `throw` in front of it, it in turn becomes an exception, right?

Comment: @Coder23 lol I'm going to add an answer at this point.

Comment: thanks, perfect @Pointy. it would be great to see as many details as possible, you would definitely have my +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript exception mechanism consists of the `throw` statement:

```
throw expression;
```

Any value, *any value at all*, can be thrown. The other part is the `try catch` structure:

```
try {
  arbitrary code
}
catch (value) {
  handler code for thrown value
}
```

The thing about `try` and `catch` is that it handles exceptions thrown by arbitrary levels of function calls within the `try` block, like most other languages with that feature.

The `catch (value)` clause is not typed, as it is in (for example) Java. Thus unlike Java multiple `catch` blocks for a single `try` doesn't make sense.

The `Error` built-in constructor is a standardized facility for creating objects to throw with commonly-useful features. There are also several subclasses of `Error` for different situations (see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/error)) though for application code they're probably not terribly useful; however, they're available. In some runtimes, `Error` instances have access to detailed information about the context of the point in the code at which they were created, such as source code line number and stack information. That makes

```
if (somethingBad) throw new Error("Something bad");
```

more useful. However, that context information is not available in all JavaScript runtimes.

Of course with modern `class` declarations it's possible to subclass `Error` if that seems useful. Personally, if I have an application that makes me feel like custom Error subclasses are important, I might take a step back and wonder why I have so many different `throw` situations. Throwing exceptions is expensive, and in most runtimes a `try catch` structure in a function will mean that very little optimization can be done because the optimizer has no clue what might happen. Thus, and this is true of all languages with a similar feature, `try catch` and `throw` should *usually* not be used as part of basic program logic. It really should be about "exceptional" situations, things that shouldn't happen but nevertheless do happen sometimes.

Comment: Excellent @Pointy +1. "*The JavaScript exception mechanism consists of the `throw` statement*" - This is worth gold, now it is clearer to me

Comment: As a footnote, I've made significant use of exception subclassing in Java, because Java syntax has typed `catch` clauses and it makes things possible that would be clumsy otherwise. I have never done it in all the JavaScript code I've written.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pointy +1 me too. I always thought that in JS there was a class as such `Exception` (like PHP, for example), but now I see that "exceptions" are any value thrown with `throw`

Comment: "*in most runtimes a try catch structure in a function will mean that very little optimization can be done*" - do you have a reference for that? The optimisation fence in V8 is long gone.

Comment: @Bergi really? That's good news. Still, as in most programming languages, exception throwing is relatively expensive by its very nature. I mean, it blows the CPU cache, and it makes use-definition and definition-use analysis hard because in the `catch` context the optimizer can't assume much.

Comment: I guess the CPU cache isn't necessarily trashed because the CPU doesn't know what's going on anyway. As I think about it, static analysis for JavaScript must be insanely complicated even without `try catch`. Anyway most of what I know about optimization is very very old knowledge, and incomplete.

Comment: Ah I thought you meant the issue where V8 was known to bail out of the optimising compiler when it encountered a `try` block - [this has been fixed](https://v8.dev/blog/high-performance-es2015#a-modern-architecture-for-a-modern-language), and functions can be optimised regardless of what syntax they use. But you're right of course that the happy path is usually optimised better than the exceptional path, and actually throwing and catching an exception has some overhead. But I guess developer experience still trumps raw speed, you should not generally try to avoid using exceptions.

Comment: @Bergi yea exceptions are fine, really great in fact, but implementing ordinary logic with exceptions (like, instead of an `if else` structure) is both weird and questionable. I suspect we are in violent agreement.

Comment: @Pointy If you can easily implement the logic with `if`/`else`, since you have both the conditions and the handler code in the same place, then of course you should prefer that. But if they are removed from each other, such as the condition in a function and the handling at the call site, then exceptions are a useful tool in one's toolbox, particularly when the error might not always be handled at the direct call site but somewhere higher. Signaling errors through the return value becomes awkward then. I'd argue it doesn't depend on how exceptional the error is but rather the handling pattern.

Comment: @Bergi yes of course, we are both experienced programmers who Do The Right Thing :)